# Pandas DataFrame interpolation with different increment by adding rows

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

So, basically, I have a DataFrame looking like this:

[image: Initial Dataframe]

and the task is to make increment of 'Depth' with 0.1 step (add new rows), also interpolate the 'Value's accordingly.

It should look like this:
(bottom part cropped because of size)

[image: Result Dataframe]

Here is the draft of code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AS', 'AS', 'AS', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'],
                   'Depth': [15, 16, 17, 10, 11, 12],
                   'Value': [100, 200, 300, 200, 300, 400]})

df['Depth']= ... #make it here with increment 0.1
df['Value'] = df['Value'].interpolate(method=linear)
df['Name'] = ... #copy it for each empty row

df.to_csv('Interpolated values.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution which will allow you to interpolate values with any variation of stepsize *(assuming steps fall neatly between integers)* and more flexibility with interpolation:

```py
my_df_list = []
step = 0.1

for label, group in df.sort_values('Depth').groupby('Name'):

    # Create a lookup dictionary for interpolation lookup
    lookup_dict = {x[0]:x[1] for x in group[['Depth', 'Value']].values}
    
    # Use np.linespace because of the strictness of start and end values
    new_index = np.linspace(
        start = group['Depth'].min(),
        stop = group['Depth'].max(),
        num = int(1/step) * np.ptp(group['Depth']) + 1
    )
    new_values = pd.Series(
        lookup_dict.get(round(x, 1)) for x in new_index
    ).interpolate()

    # Create a tmp df with your values
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'Name': [label] * len(new_index),
        'Depth': new_index, 
        'Value':new_values
    })
    my_df_list.append(df_tmp)

# Finally, combine all dfs
df_final = pd.concat(my_df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

```
    Name    Depth   Value
0   AS      15.0    100.0
1   AS      15.1    110.0
...
19  AS      16.9    290.0
20  AS      17.0    300.0
21  DB      10.0    200.0
22  DB      10.1    210.0
...
39  DB      11.8    380.0
40  DB      11.9    390.0
41  DB      12.0    400.0
```

Comment: This is some high level programming skill. I have had some difficulties in understanding this code but it works exactly as it should. I owe you big time. Thanks!

Comment: Consider taking it apart and putting it back together. Will give you a good understanding of what is occuring on a lower level behind pandas operations. @OrkhanMammadov

Answer (score 2):

### Part 1:

I choose not to use iteration, assign new values to the whole column instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AS', 'AS', 'AS', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'], 
                   'Depth': [15, 16, 17, 10, 11, 12], 
                   'Value':[100, 200, 300, 200, 300, 400]
                  })
```

Output:

```
  Name  Depth  Value
0   AS     15    100
1   AS     16    200
2   AS     17    300
3   DB     10    200
4   DB     11    300
5   DB     12    400
```

---

1. use `len` to get the length of the column.
2. `df[column][0]` to get the initial value. If you do have a specific initial value then just skip this step. Assign your initial value to it.

```
ini_1 = df['Depth'][0] # initial value
ini_2 = df['Value'][0] # initial value
length = len(df)
step_1 = 0.1
step_2 = 10

df['Depth'] = np.arange(ini_1, ini_1+length*step_1, step_1)
df['Value'] = np.arange(ini_2, ini_2+length*step_2, step_2)
```

output

```
  Name  Depth  Value
0   AS   15.0    100
1   AS   15.1    110
2   AS   15.2    120
3   DB   15.3    130
4   DB   15.4    140
5   DB   15.5    150
```

Since we don't know the variant regulation between `Name` and `Depth`, but it's another aspect that avoids iterate into every single row.

---

### Part 2:

Suppose every name-depth group expands to 10 items
and follow the increment of 0.1 and 10 on `Depth` and `Value` respectively.

Here's the step:

1. load the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AS', 'AS', 'AS', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'], 
                   'Depth': [15, 16, 17, 10, 11, 12], 
                   'Value':[100, 200, 300, 200, 300, 400]
                  })
```

2. expand `df` to 10X:

```
dfn = pd.concat([df]*10,ignore_index=False).sort_index()
```

3. It's an arithmetic progression:
   for `Depth` a = 0, d = 0.1, length = 10
   for `Value` a = 0, d = 10, length = 10
   Taking them as vector(1D array) summation in each `Name-Depth` group:

```
a = 0
d_depth = 0.1
d_value = 10
length = 10
arithmetric_1 = [round(a + d_depth * (n - 1),2) for n in range(1, length + 1)] # arithmetic progression series for Depth
arithmetric_2 = [round(a + d_value * (n - 1),2) for n in range(1, length + 1)] # arithmetic progression series for Value
```

4. the main part

```
for i in set(dfn.index):
    dfn.loc[i,'Depth'] = dfn.loc[i,'Depth'].array + arithmetric_1
    dfn.loc[i,'Value'] = dfn.loc[i,'Value'].array + arithmetric_2
```

summary:
now you get dataframe `dfn` as the result base on the assumption. This manipulation try to decrease the loop-times, and use vector aspect to deal with the problem(if you have huge datasets).

```
Name Depth  Value
0   AS  15.0    100
0   AS  15.1    110
0   AS  15.2    120
0   AS  15.3    130
0   AS  15.4    140
0   AS  15.5    150
0   AS  15.6    160
0   AS  15.7    170
0   AS  15.8    180
0   AS  15.9    190
1   AS  16.0    200
1   AS  16.1    210
1   AS  16.2    220
1   AS  16.3    230
1   AS  16.4    240
1   AS  16.5    250
1   AS  16.6    260
1   AS  16.7    270
1   AS  16.8    280
1   AS  16.9    290
2   AS  17.0    300
2   AS  17.1    310
       :
       :
```

Comment: @Baron, Thanks for your efforts! I've found a lot of useful hints for myself here, especially in Part 2. 
I was just wondering if there is a more convenient way to interpolate 'Value's? not just add to it 10, as if I have more complicated dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The following given solution will solve the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AS', 'AS', 'AS', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'],
                   'Depth': [15, 16, 17, 10, 11, 12],
                   'Value':[100, 200, 300, 200, 300, 400]})

counter = 0.0
def add(val):
    global counter
    if counter <=0.9:
        val = val+counter
        counter+=0.1
        return val
    else:
        counter=0.1
        return val

# Duplicate each rows 10 times and sort using the index 
df = pd.concat([df]*10).sort_index()
# Apply add function on the depth
df['Depth'] = df['Depth'].apply(add)
# Reset the index
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
# Increment the value by 10 based on the last value
for idx in range(1,len(df)):
    df.loc[idx, 'Value'] = df.loc[idx-1,'Value']+10
```

Output:

```
   Name  Depth  Value
0    AS   15.0    100
1    AS   15.1    110
2    AS   15.2    120
3    AS   15.3    130
4    AS   15.4    140
5    AS   15.5    150
6    AS   15.6    160
7    AS   15.7    170
8    AS   15.8    180
9    AS   15.9    190
10   AS   16.0    200
11   AS   16.1    210
12   AS   16.2    220
13   AS   16.3    230
14   AS   16.4    240
```

Comment: I will stick to the interpolation for the Value column as there are more complicated numbers in reality. But overall this answer solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear Gurjot, apparently the answer from Mr. Yaakov Bressler fits better to what I was needed, including interpolation problem. I will upvote your response. Thanks again.